# How to add additional border on the left and add additional boxes in the right corner with a label

Tags: tikz-pgf

Trying to draw diagrams from [Problem Frames](http://oro.open.ac.uk/3334/1/re02.hall.pdf) paper.

How can I create this borders on the left and add additional boxes in the right corner with a label. Is it also possible to add an additional line on both sides?

This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

This where I stuck now:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\tikzset{element/.style={
  draw,
  thick,
  node distance=1.5cm,
  minimum width=1.5cm,
  minimum height=1cm
  },
 desinedDomain/.style={element},
 machine/.style={element},
 requirement/.style={element,circle,dotted}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (m) [machine] {machine};
  \node (d1) [desinedDomain, above right=of m] {domain1};
  \node (d2) [element, below right=of m] {domain2};
  \node (r1) [requirement, below right=of d1] {domain3};

  \draw (m) -- (d1) node[midway,left] {a};
  \draw (m) -- (d2) node[midway,above] {b};
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- (d1) node[midway,below] {c};
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- (d2) node[midway,above] {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Problem Frames}
\label{fig:pf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, more sophisticated and distinct different (comparison to my firs answer, this is reason why I decided for new answer) solution.

In this solution the "subelements" are defined as inside labels in node "element". They can be arbitrary positioned inside node similarly as standard labels can be is positioned outside of node with difference that they are anchored to inside side of node's anchors. For design of node "machine" I exploit `multipart` node and possibility, that of including node content between other node parameters.

Consequently the picture code is notable more concise from the first solution. Complete MWE now is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzsavelastnodename#1{\let#1=\tikz@last@fig@name}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    node distance=0mm and 15mm,
element/.style={%
    draw, thick,
    minimum size=11mm, inner xsep=5mm,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\tikzsavelastnodename\tikzsavednodename}},#1
                },
subelement/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    append after command =
    {node[draw,thick,minimum size=3mm,
          inner sep=2pt] at (\tikzsavednodename.#1) [anchor=#1] {#2}}
                            },
machine/.style={%
     shape=rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
     rectangle split parts=3,
     rectangle split empty part width=-3mm,
     draw, thick, 
     minimum height=11mm, inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0mm,
     node contents={\nodepart{three}\ #1\ }
             },
requirement/.style={%
    element, inner sep=2mm, circle, dotted}
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (m)  [machine=machine];
\node (d1) [element,
            subelement=south east:C,
            above right=of m]   {domain1};
\node (d2) [element,
            subelement=south east:B,
            below right=of m]   {domain2};
\node (r1) [requirement, 
            below right=of d1]  {domain3};
%
  \draw (m) -- node[above] {a}   (d1)
        (m) -- node[above] {b}   (d2);
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- node[above] {c} (d1);
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- node[above] {d} (d2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Obtained picture is similar as in the my first answer:

[image]

**Edit:** Today I observe, that I had uploaded my MWE twice. So I remove surplus MWE and slightly (hopefully) improve description of it.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward solution is add two small nodes placed inside "domain1" and "domain2" node:

[image]

For above picture I define `subelement` style for small nodes. Beside this, I move `node distance` to common parameter in `tikzset`, slightly change it (that result is more similar to shoved image in question), for all nodes with rectangle shape use style `element`. And that is:

**Edit:** ups, I forgot on one of sub question. Now it is added. For lines on left side of node "machine, I define new style `machine` and add two those nodes on the left size "machine" node.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\tikzset{%
    node distance=3mm and 15mm,
element/.style={
    draw,
    thick,
    minimum width=1.7cm,
    minimum height=1cm
    },
machine/.style={
    element,
    minimum width=0cm, outer sep=0pt,

subelement/.style={
  draw,
  thick,
  inner sep= 1pt, 
  minimum size=3mm,
  }, 
requirement/.style={element,circle,dotted}
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (m)  [element] {machine};
    \node (d1) [element,above right=of m] {domain1};
\node[subelement,above left] at (d1.south east) {C};
    \node (d2) [element,below right=of m] {domain2};
\node[subelement,above left] at (d2.south east) {B};
    \node (r1) [requirement, below right=of d1] {domain3};
%
  \draw (m) -- node[above] {a}   (d1) 
        (m) -- node[above] {b}   (d2);
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- node[above] {c} (d1);
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- node[above] {d} (d2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but it is not allowed to take both. I decided for the answer given by @Alenanno, because his code had viewer nodes.

Comment: @Paul, it is ok. My above solution is very elementary, so I decided to create new one (based on one of my similar picture) which is far more concise and general. See, if it is valuable for you.

Answer (score 2):

For the lines, you can use `\pgfextra` and draw lines using the node's anchors. For the label, you can use a label as an argument for the style.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\tikzset{
    element/.style={
        draw,
        thick,
        node distance=1.5cm,
        minimum width=1.5cm,
        minimum height=1cm
    },
    desinedDomain/.style={element,
        label={[draw, anchor=south east, thick, inner sep=0, minimum size=3mm, shift={(\tikzlastnode.south east)}]#1}
    },
    machine/.style={element,append after command={\pgfextra{
        \draw[thick] (\tikzlastnode.south west)++(0,.5\pgflinewidth) --++ (-1mm,0) |- ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-.5\pgflinewidth)$);
        \draw[thick] (\tikzlastnode.south west)++(0,.5\pgflinewidth) --++ (-2mm,0) |- ($(\tikzlastnode.north west)+(0,-.5\pgflinewidth)$);
    }}},
    requirement/.style={element,circle,dotted}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (m) [machine] {machine};
  \node (d1) [desinedDomain=c, above right=of m] {domain1};
  \node (d2) [element, below right=of m] {domain2};
  \node (r1) [requirement, below right=of d1] {domain3};

  \draw (m) -- (d1) node[midway,left] {a};
  \draw (m) -- (d2) node[midway,above] {b};
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- (d1) node[midway,below] {c};
  \draw[dashed,->] (r1) -- (d2) node[midway,above] {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```